# Google API Python Client - 401 Invalid Credentials - Google Drive

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I use a Google service account to access users of an organization using directory API and then use drive API to perform certain file operations on users.

It works fine for few users and for others, the drive API call is returning the following error when trying to list the user's files (For that matter any drive API call on that user is returning the same error).

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json&maxResults=1000 returned "Invalid Credentials">

Quoting from this [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors) documentation about 401 error,

"Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token."

I have a valid access token which is not expired. And the user for which this error message seen is not suspended either.

Are there any other reasons as to why Google sends this error?

Comment: How do you know the access token has not expired?

Comment: Current time is less than the expiry time of the access token.

Comment: tokens don't have an expiry time because the clocks of the server and the client aren't guaranteed to be in sync. They have an expires_in ms.